# Disgusting aliens in wooden spaceships

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember reading a story, a many years ago, about a group of aliens reaching Earth.  They were viewed with disgust by us because they spent their lives wallowing in mud and waste (possibly their own excrement??).  Their spacecraft was made of some sort of vegetable material.  I don't think we'd worked out a way to communicate.

Anyone have any idea what the story was?

Comment: When was "many years ago?"  Was this a short story?  Did you read it in an anthology, a magazine or online?

Comment: @DavidW - between thirty and fifty years ago, I can't remember if it was a short story, a novella or a novel.  I don't think it was in a magazine.  Sorry I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe this is *[The Dark Light Years](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1351129.The_Dark_Light_Years)* (1964) by Brian W. Aldiss.

According to [this review](https://yellowedandcreased.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/the-dark-light-years-brian-aldiss/), the story documents the first contact between humanity and an alien species called the Utod, who travel in wooden spacecraft and wallow in their own filth.

> Humanity has met many species of semi-sapient lifeforms on its expansion across the galaxies, but had never discovered another intelligent race before. That changed when a group of explorers ran into the utod. Hippopotomi-sized, two-headed mammals **that wallow in mud and their own filth, traversing the galaxy in wooden spacecraft,** the utod are gentle creatures who feel no pain, can change their gender, and communicate in a complex series of whistles and hoots from their eight orifaces. Needless to say, humanity’s gut instinct on first contact is to gun down all but two of them. Taken back to the London Exozoo, the sharpest human minds attempt to converse with the remaining creatures, only to see them fail every man-made test for intelligence. Meanwhile, the utod refuse to open communications with this strange race of two-legged creatures whose second orifice is hidden under clothing, and who shun the holiness of a middenwallow in favor of abject cleanliness. By the end, it becomes one man’s destiny to live with the utod and learn their ways.

Comment: - That's it!!  Thanks very much!

Comment: The review is explicitly copyrighted; while the "fair use" doctrine could cover excerpting the paragraph containing the bolded portion and the sentence "Whether or not they are intelligent at all is a matter of some controversy on Earth, since they have resisted all attempts at communication on the part of their captors", (which are sufficient to confirm the ID), unless you're Thomas M. Wagner or got permission, it's surely not legal to copy/paste the entire review, so I suggest cutting it down to those two parts.

Comment: I'll see if I can find a different source altogether, just to be extra safe.